# How to share global variables in Node.js BETWEEN 2 TERMINALS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

This question is different from its simple variant.

I have a `config.js` file that I am using as a simple file to store global variable across files.

```js
// config.js
module.exports = {
  printer: 'default_uninitialized_printer',
};

// ----
// script.js
let config = require('./config.js');
let server = require('./server.js');

config.printer = 'HP-Printer-REAL';
await sleep(5000);
// sleep() method is declared and it works. It waits 5 seconds

server.getPrinter();

// ----
// server.js
let config = require('./config.js');
module.exports{
  getPrinter: function() {
    console.log('Printer = ' + config.printer);
  },
}

// -----
// OUTPUT LOG in terminal

    Printer = default_uninitialized_printer
```

Normally, the above sample code shall print 'Printer = HP-Printer-REAL'.

However, The printer value is not changed because I have 2 terminals: 1 for the server.js; and 1 for the script.js.

My server.js terminal is the real backend server for my full-stack project.

My script.js terminal is a terminal that I use to test some functions (Selenium and Chokidar; not related to this question).

I have internal console.logs and I see that `config.printer` value for script.js file is updated, obviously.

I also changed the `config.js` file a little:

```js
var printer = 'default_uninitialized_printer';
module.exports = {
    getPrinter: function() {
        return printer;
    },
    setPrinter: function(value) {
        printer = value;
    },
};
```

But of course, it had the same logical error.

I now plan to use my MongoDB to save this printer value. But can anyone give me a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This design seems overly complicated for no good reason. Why not simply let `server.js` maintain the globals, then have `script.js` query `server.js` to obtain/change them?

Comment: I simplified my explanation.  In actuality, my `server.js` terminal has a `chokidar` npm package (watcher) script that gets activated when I download a file in a specific directory. This chokidar.js file needs the printer variable that is set by the script.js file. My config.js global variable holder design is a fairly normal design, I think.

Comment: I will try to store the `printer` variable inside my `chokidar.js` file and let my `script.js` file edit this variable. I will get back to you. Thank you

Comment: So `server.js` is not a server at all. Why not write a super simple REST server to store the globals, with GET to obtain a value, PUT to set a value?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply. I decided to use my database for this test. My database helps me share the printer variable easily. (Edit: Please consider this post closed/solved). To clarify, my server terminal is actually an Express.js/Mongoose server. This server 'require's or calls the `chokidar.js` file. Thank you for your time and willingness to help me. I realize now that 2 terminals cannot share the same variable that easily without preparing something that I don't want to know.